# Sort A List of Tuples By Lowest Value

Tags: python

Supposed I have a list of tuples:

```
my_list = [(1, 4), (3, 0), (6, 2), (3, 8)]
```

How do I sort this list by the minimum value in the tuple, regardless of position? My final list will be as follows:

```
my_sorted_list = [(3, 0), (1, 4), (6, 2), (3, 8)]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `key` parameter, to either `.sort` or `sorted`:

```
>>> my_list = [(1, 4), (3, 0), (6, 2), (3, 8)]
>>> sorted(my_list, key=min)
[(3, 0), (1, 4), (6, 2), (3, 8)]
```

Comment: `sorted(my_list, key=max) == sorted(my_list, key=min)` is True, seems strange.

Comment: @VidulPetrov: that's just a quirk of the input data.  The min and max values by tuple for the sorted `my_list` are `(0, 1, 2, 3)` and `(3, 4, 6, 8)`; if (3,8) were replaced by (3, -2) the sorted orders would differ.

Answer (score 2):

```
my_sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=min)
```

Comment: Except `my_sorted_list` would be an iterator instead of a list.

Comment: @robert: In Python 2.7.2 sorted() returns a list. It may well return a generator in Python 3; in that case, you could either use it as a generator or wrap it in a call to list().

Comment: Actually, it returns a list in both. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x[0] if x[0] < x[1] else x[1])
```

Comment: That sorts by the key, not value of the tuple. Can you changed the code?

Comment: @Radu: Huh? It's sorts using the value the key function returns. In this case the function is a lambda that receives each tuple as an input argument and then selects and returns the lower of the two values in it. Try it and you will see it works just fine. It also has slightly less overhead than the accepted answer which calls the built-in min() function on each tuple.